# Record callback function in Swift with Superpowered or AudioKit audio libraries

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit, superpowered

My app (coded in swift) does realtime processing based on audio signals.

I need to get a function with the left and right buffers coming from the input (2 channels from USB microphone) and one function with buffers for the output (2 channels as well).

I used to use EZAudio but I have memory problem with 2 channels 96K format. And as EZAudio stopped, I would like to change to either Superpowered or Audiokit.

My problem is: I cannot get in any of these libraries the functions with the buffers.

Superpowered: 
I added #import "SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO.h" in the bridge header.

I added SuperpoweredIOSAudioIODelegate in my ViewController.
This automatically added the interruption, permission and mapchannels functions, but not audioProcessingCallback.

I tried the following things:

```
audio = SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO(delegate: self, preferredBufferSize: 12, preferredMinimumSamplerate: 96000, audioSessionCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, channels: 2, audioProcessingCallback: audioProcessingCallback, clientdata: UnsafeMutablePointer)
audio.start()
```

and

```
func audioProcessingCallback(buffers: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>>, inputChannels: UInt32, outputChannels: UInt32, numberOfSamples: UInt32, sampleRate: UInt32, hostTime: UInt64) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

But I get the error:

> Cannot convert value of type
>   '(UnsafeMutablePointer>, UInt32, UInt32,
>   UInt32, UInt32, UInt64) -> Bool' to expected argument type
>   'audioProcessingCallback!' (aka
>   'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<@convention(c)
>   (Optional,
>   Optional>>>,
>   UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt32, UInt64) -> Bool>')

I could not find any examples of this library with Swift...

With AudioKit, here is what I did:

```
let mic = AKMicrophone()
installTap(mic)
AudioKit.output = mic
AudioKit.start()

func installTap(_ input:AKNode) {
        input.avAudioNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: AudioKit.format) { [weak self] (buffer, time) -> Void in
            self?.signalTracker(didReceivedBuffer: buffer, atTime: time)
        }
    }

func signalTracker(didReceivedBuffer buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, atTime time: AVAudioTime){
        let samples = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData?[0], count:1024)
        audioProcess.ProcessDataCaptureWithBuffer(samples, numberOfSamples: UInt32(1024))
    }
```

It can get the coming buffers in my algorithm, but it seems to be not in "realtime", I mean, very slow..(sorry, hard to explain.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to do realtime processing, you should not use Swift (or ObjC).  Currently the way to do this in AudioKit is to create an AUAudioUnit subclass and do your processing within it.  However, if you just need the audio tap to be faster, then AKLazyTap is an good solution.  It's different from a normal tap in that you have to poll it for data, but this method allows for buffer re-use, so you can call it as quickly as you'd like.

Here's an example of using AKLazyTap to get peak:

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let microphone = AKMicrophone()
    var tap: AKLazyTap?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        AudioKit.output = microphone
        AKSettings.ioBufferDuration = 0.002 // This is to decrease latency for faster callbacks.

        tap = AKLazyTap(node: microphone.avAudioNode)

        guard tap != nil,
            let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: microphone.avAudioNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0), frameCapacity: 44100) else {
            fatalError()
        }

        // Your timer should fire equal to or faster than your buffer duration
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: AKSettings.ioBufferDuration / 2, repeats: true) { _ in

            var timeStamp = AudioTimeStamp()
            self.tap?.fillNextBuffer(buffer, timeStamp: &timeStamp)

            if buffer.frameLength == 0 { return } // This is important, since we're polling for samples, sometimes it's empty, and sometimes it will be double what it was the last call.

            let leftMono = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buffer.floatChannelData?[0], count:Int(buffer.frameLength))
            var peak = Float(0)
            for sample in leftMono {
                peak = max(peak, fabsf(sample))
            }
            print("number of samples \(buffer.frameLength) peak \(peak)")

        }

        AudioKit.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: From the answer below (Gabor Szanto), taps are indeed a bit slow. And as I need a perfect timestamp, i prefer to switch to Superpowered. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer to include time stamps, which are accurate.

Comment: The way this tap is set up, it's not at all slow.  In this example it's just as fast as the underlying C callbacks, but the data has been moved off of the audio thread so that Swift/ObjC can be used.  This make it ideal for quick analysis for things like triggering UI based on the audio stream.  The best way to check the speed is to measure. Try the tap in my example, then compare the buffer.frameLength with the buffer.frameLength in the AVAudioNode tap, you'll see that AKLazyTap is about 20 times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try to implement it. Do you know why the maximum peak I can get is 0.707 instead of 1.0? Is there a limitation or a gain below 1 somewhere?

Comment: .707 sounds like the result of getting the RMS.  Try getting the peak using the method shown above.

Comment: I did, I copied / paste your code entirely. I still have this sqrt(value) for samples. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

Superpowered is a C++ API, because Swift is not recommended for real-time processing. Write your audio processing code in C++. "Taps" are slow, use SuperpoweredIOSAudioIO to get the audio in real-time.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, my algorithm is not that big and works in both Swift and Objective-C. However, I need a perfect timestamp. I can totally rework in C++ (just in case!) in a different class. But still, I'd like to call the main function of the algorithm from my VC (in Swift), but I didn't manage to implement the audioProcessingCallback function. Could you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Use Objective-C++ (that is Objective-C but can use C++, just rename your .m file to .mm). Then bridge that to Swift.